# Is 'go easy on me ' correct?

Tags: expressions

I know that 'go easy on somebody/something' is used, but I've never heard 'go easy on me'.
For example: "Go easy on me if I make a mistake though!"

Can the speaker itself be used as the object when using this expression? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find I have been in error. I am correcting before the Grammar Police arrive "To serve and Correct".

The sentence is an *Imperative* and as such the subject, You, is implied. The speaker *is not* the subject here. The one *spoken to* is the subject.

As pointed out in thoughtco.com
Imperative sentences may seem to have no subject, but the implied subject is you, or, as it is properly called, "you understood".

To go easy means to use less than the standard or usual amount of force of whatever kind against the "victim". This can be used in many ways. If I, the young man, am subject to the amorous assault of a beautiful woman I might ask her to "Go easy on me" if I, unaccountably, wished her not to succeed in her efforts. Ain't fiction grand?

Comment: Thanks! Another question: why is speaker the subject and not the object?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It inspired me to examine my answer and make the correction.